# Null pointer exception while deleting an element from doubly linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, nullpointerexception

The code is working fine when I try to delete any element for some indices but for some others it is not working. For example, Whenever I try to delete by passing `delete(1)` it may work and if I try with `delete(2)` it may show `NullPointerException`. Here is the code :

```
    Node head;
    
    public void insert(int data)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        node.next = null;
        node.prev = null;
        if(head == null)
        {
            head = node;
            return;
        }
        Node n = head;
        while(n.next!=null)
        {
            n = n.next;
        }
        node.prev = n;
        n.next = node;
    }
    
    public void show()
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Doubly Linked List is empty so please enter values first.");
            return;
        }
        Node n = head;
        while(n.next!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(n.data);
            n = n.next;
        }
        System.out.println(n.data);
    }


    public void delete(int index)
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            System.out.println("List is empty.");
            return;
        }
        if(index == 0)
        {
            head = head.next;
            head.prev = null;
            return;
        }
        Node n = head;
        for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
        {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.prev.next = n.next;
        n.next.prev = n.prev;
    }
}
```

So this is my code and You can see the delete method over there. I even run through debug mode, it is showing error at `n.prev.next = n.next`
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't check if n.next is null.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger? How long is your list?

Comment: Please read about [MRE]. It would have been nice to be able to copy the code and run it to see the missing information. For one thing, it would have been nice to see the entire stack trace of the exception.

Comment: If you try to remove the last element, you will get `n==null`

Comment: @jhamon I do tried with debugger. It is showing error at  n.prev.next = n.next  . Also sometimes even last element removal is working. To be specific, if my list is: 5,10,15,20,25. When I try to delete '10' ie, index '1' it is showing error. For remaining elements it is working fine.

Comment: @NomadMaker I Just sent the methods that I used in my code. Just to see if at all there are any interlinked errors in them.

Comment: Think about all the corner cases and try to make them work, e.g., empty list, only one element etc. Your method is broken for a case with only one element - head = head.next() = null and then you do head.prev -> NullPointerException. Also check on wich **line** you get the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran your code, the `NullPointerException` occurred on this line:

```java
n.next.prev = n.prev;
```

and not on the line you said in your question.

The `NullPointerException` occurs when you delete the last `Node` in the list. This is because the value of `next` for the last `Node` in the list is null. So `n.next` is null and therefore `n.next.prev` throws `NullPointerException`.

You need to check whether `n.next` is null and only if it isn't you can execute the code: `n.next.prev = n.prev`.

Also, you need to check the value of parameter `index` in method `delete()`. One way would be to keep track of the number of elements in the list.

The below code incorporates the changes described. The parts I added are preceded by the comment *Change here*

```java
public class DbLnkLst {
    private static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node prev;
    }

    Node head;
    
    public void insert(int data)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        node.next = null;
        node.prev = null;
        if(head == null)
        {
            head = node;
            return;
        }
        Node n = head;
        while(n.next!=null)
        {
            n = n.next;
        }
        node.prev = n;
        n.next = node;
    }
    
    public void show()
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Doubly Linked List is empty so please enter values first.");
            return;
        }
        Node n = head;
        while(n.next!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(n.data);
            n = n.next;
        }
        System.out.println(n.data);
    }


    public void delete(int index)
    {
        // Change here.
        if (index < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative index: " + index);
        }

        if(head == null)
        {
            System.out.println("List is empty.");
            return;
        }
        if(index == 0)
        {
            head = head.next;
            head.prev = null;
            return;
        }
        Node n = head;
        for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
        {
            // Change here.
            if (n.next == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid index: " + index);
            }

            n = n.next;
        }
        n.prev.next = n.next;

        // Change here.
        if (n.next != null) {
            n.next.prev = n.prev;
        }
    }

    /**
     * For testing the class.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DbLnkLst list = new DbLnkLst();
        list.insert(0);
        list.insert(1);
        list.insert(2);
        System.out.println("List is:");
        list.show();
        list.delete(2);
        System.out.println("After 'delete(2)', list is:");
        list.show();
        System.out.println("Try 'delete(2)' again.");
        list.delete(2);
    }
}
```

The output from running the above code is below:

```
List is:
0
1
2
After 'delete(2)', list is:
0
1
Try 'delete(2)' again.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid index: 2
    at genrlprj/misctsts.DbLnkLst.delete(DbLnkLst.java:73)
    at genrlprj/misctsts.DbLnkLst.main(DbLnkLst.java:100)
```